# Regex to match colon and numbers

Tags: regex

I am writing regex to match the pattern like this.

```
abc:123-12-4

abc: It should be exact match including colon
123   Number match any length
-     Exact Match
12    Number Match any length
-     Exact match
4     Exact match
```

Any ideas how it can be done in a simpler way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
^abc:[0-9]+-[0-9]+-4$
```